# CreateDirectory in Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments is denied

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, create-directory

I have a file stream that I want to store in iOS under a subfolder under the SpecialFolder enum.

The `FileStream` constructor wants the subfolder structure to exist first and when I try to create it, I get UnauthorizedAccessException.

Suppose my intended location is

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/folder1/file1.xls";
```

which, in my session, resolves to

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/035ECE7D-0E9F-4DF9-927B-B79FB31AEE01/Documents/folder1/file1.xls
```

Then I make sure the location exists

```
if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
}
```

which, [according](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system) to Microsoft, should work

Instead of having the subfolder created and the file stream happily saving the file into it, the `CreateDirectory` method throws this:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/035ECE7D-0E9F-4DF9-927B-B79FB31AEE01" is denied.
```

I thought `MyDocuments` was free to do stuff in? I've seen no documentation that says I have to apply for permission first. Where should I be creating folders?

Comment: have you set the appropriate permissions in the Android manifest?

Comment: Not Android, iOS

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Is this the simulator?  Can you access that path from Terminal?

Comment: I just create a new project and add these two line `string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/folder1/file1.xls";` ,`Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);`. It works both on simulator and a real device.  Did you iphone trust the computer? Is there any other codes you haven't post?

Answer (score 0):

If you code with Visual Studio, try to run the program in administrator (Visual Studio), after run your project. Maybe it’s the good solution.

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with permissions within the Android filesystem

Comment: Ok, sorry... I wasn't understand the question. I can’t help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create platform specific classes for working with saving files and use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) for calling your methods. For iOS app I used this folder enum: `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` and that worked for me.